# Git Installation Returns Error 404 On RHEL

Tags: linux, bash, git, metadata, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to install Git in my REHL but failed. I have also clean up metadata and everything else by running `sudo yum clean metadata` and `sudo yum clean all` but still, the error persists again and again. Trying for the forth times now tho.

I also have checked the network, yes, my network is fine. My firewall? :O

#### Error code

`bash-4.1$ sudo yum install git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Repository centosplus is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository contrib is listed more than once in the configuration
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.upsi.edu.my
 * extras: mirror.upsi.edu.my
 * updates: mirror.upsi.edu.my
Artica          |  951 B     00:00

Artica/primary  | 7.8 kB     00:00

Artica                       33/33

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6//repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: EPEL. Please verify its path and try again`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the url `http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6//repodata/repomd.xml`. Notice anything missing? In between those two slashes should be your architecture.

Take a look at the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`

On my RHEL 7 machine it looks like this

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
priority=2
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
```

Make sure that there's a `$basearch` at the end of the `baseurl`and `mirrorlist` entries.

If it's there then something's gone wrong and this variable isn't being set correctly. If you just want it fixed now you can replace `$basearch` with `x86_64` (or whatever your architecture is) and go on with your life.

To start investigating further you can use the command `yum-debug-dump` (which annoyingly writes to a file) to see a printout of all the variables.

Edit: For reference, if `$basearch` isn't being set correctly something is very messed up on your system as it isn't set anywhere but is derived from the `uname(2)` system call.

> It derives the $releasever value from the version number of the
>   package configured as "distroverpkg" (actually, whatever "provides"
>   that in RPM parlance) in /etc/yum.conf, and $basearch from a call to
>   the operating system's uname(2) function.
>
> Paul.
>   --  Paul Howarth

[RedHat Archives](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2005-May/msg03438.html)

Comment: I have tried to replace $basearch with x86_64 but still failed.

`Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-5&arch=x86_64 error was
12: Timeout on http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-5&arch=x86_64: (28, 'connect() timed out!')`

Comment: Something weird is going on. In your question you were trying to access EPEL 6 but this suggests you're trying to access EPEL 5. Your best bet would be to remove any package called `epel-release` on your system, make sure all the epel repo files are cleared out from `/etc/yum.repos.d` and start fresh with the latest release http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm  Remember to run `yum makecache` after you install the package.